# Existence of the Dirac δ-function defined as a distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I came across a definition of the δ-function as a generalized function in [Mathematics Handbook for Science and Engineering](https://www.worldcat.org/title/mathematics-handbook-for-science-and-engineering/oclc/878001261&referer=brief_results) which made me curious.

They first define a *test function* $\varphi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ satisfying

> 1) $\varphi \in \mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$
>
> 2) $\displaystyle\lim_{|t|\to\infty} t^p \frac{\mathrm d^q \varphi(t)}{\mathrm dt^q} = 0$ for all $p,q\geq 0$

and denote the class of all test functions $S$.

They then define a sequence $\displaystyle\{\varphi_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ with $\varphi_k \in S$ as *zero sequence* in $S$ if and only if

> $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \max_{t \in \mathbb R} \left| \frac{\mathrm d^q \varphi(t)}{\mathrm dt^q}\right| = 0$ for all $p,q\geq 0.$

They then denote the value of a functional $f : S \to \mathbb C$ as $(f|\varphi)$ and define a *distribution* as a continuous linear functional on $S$, i.e. for all $\varphi, \psi \in S$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$ we have

> $(f|\alpha \varphi + \beta \psi) = \alpha(f|\varphi) + \beta(f|\psi)$
>
> and
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} (f|\varphi_k) \equiv 0$ for all zero sequences $\displaystyle\{\varphi_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ in $S$

They then let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a piece-wise continuous function satisfying the integral equation

> $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} \left( 1+ t^2\right)^{-m} \left|g(t)\right| \; \mathrm dt < \infty$ for some $m \in \mathbb Z.$

Then

> $(f|\varphi) = \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R} g(t) \varphi(t) \; \mathrm dt$

is said to define a *regular* distribution. *Non-regular* distributions are called *singular*.

Finally, they define the Dirac $\delta$-function as a singular distribution by

> $(\delta|\varphi) = \varphi(0)$

**Now, surely you can claim that this is a sound definition. Could one prove the existence of a such functional?**

Comment: What do you mean by "eventual uniqueness"?  Uniqueness is completely obvious, since we have defined exactly what $\delta$ is.  All that needs to be checked is that this definition is actually continuous and linear.

Comment: The distributions defined here are often called *tempered distributions* and are those for which the Fourier transform can be defined. A bigger class of distributions is defined as continuous linear functionals on $C_c^\infty$, the space of infinately differentiable functions with compact support.

Comment: @EricWofsey. Probably Markus has confused with the Swedish word 'eventuell' meaning 'possible'. Thus it should actually read "possible uniqueness".

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah, obviously the uniqueness is trivial. What's not trivial is that it's a valid distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was another distribution $\eta$ with $(\eta|\varphi) = \varphi(0)$ for all test functions $\varphi$, then $(\eta-\delta|\varphi) = (\eta|\varphi) - (\delta|\varphi) = \varphi(0) - \varphi(0) = 0$

Hence $\eta-\delta = 0\iff \eta = \delta$ which shows uniqueness.

Existence is simply a consequence of the definition. $\delta:S\to\mathbb C, \varphi \to \varphi(0)$  *is* a continuous linear functional on S. Hence $\delta$ exists as an element of the dual space $S^*$.

**Remark:** Obviously every element of $S^*$ is unique. (Either $a=b$ or $a\neq b$). My guess is that you rather confused this with the observation that for **regular** distributions, there might be different **functions** $f,g$ inducing the same distribution. If $\int \varphi(x) f(x) dx = \int \varphi(x) g(x) dx$ for all test functions $\varphi$, we can only conclude that $f(x)-g(x)$ is orthogonal to all test functions. Depending on the space of test functions such $f,g$ might exist or not. This however does not apply to the dirac delta. The reason we still write $\int \varphi(x)\delta(x) dx$ instead of say $\delta(\varphi)$ is because of [Riesz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

The theorem states that if $H$ is a Hilbert space, then any coninuous linear functional $\psi$ on $H$ takes the form $\psi(\varphi) = (f_\psi,\varphi)$ for some $f_\psi\in H$. Note that $S$ is not a Hilbert-space! Since $\delta$ is provably non-regular, you cannot find $f_\delta\in S$ such that $\delta(\varphi) = (f_\delta,\varphi)$ for all $\varphi$. But it motivates why we carry on with the notation $\int \varphi(x)\delta(x) dx :=\delta(\varphi)$ **as if** the dirac delta existed as a function.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but how does $(\eta - \delta|\varphi) = 0 \implies \eta = \delta$?

Comment: I also find it strange you can just "declare" the existence of $\delta$ without actually showing a such functional exists. How do we know a functional $\delta$ satisfying $\begin{cases}(\delta|\alpha \varphi + \beta \psi) = \alpha(\delta|\varphi) + \beta(\delta|\psi) \\ \displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} (\delta|\varphi_k) \equiv 0 \\ (\delta|\varphi) = \varphi(0) \end{cases}$ really exists?

Comment: @K.Power The function $x \mapsto x^2$ exists because we can show that a such function really satisfies the definition of a function (which may depend on which foundation you might use). So, to re-state my question: how do we know $\delta|\varphi) = \varphi(0)$ is actually valid and sound? That is, how do we know $(\delta|\varphi) = \varphi(0)$ really defines a singular distribution?

Comment: Tjenare, @MarkusKlyver! Two functions are equal iff their values are equal for all arguments. In the case of linear functionals this means that the functionals $u$ and $v$ are equal iff $(u|\varphi) = (v|\varphi)$ for all $\phi$ in the domain.

Comment: @MarkusKlyver Check out my remark. I am curious about your idea what 'existence' is supposed to mean. By definition, the dirac delta is the function that maps an element $\varphi$ of the function space $S$ onto its value at the origin   $\varphi(0)$.  This exists first and foremost simply as a set-theoretic map. There is no doubt about its existence. Now its easy to show that this map indeed defines a continuous linear functional on $S$. And quite a bit harder to prove it is non-regular.

Comment: @Hyperplane Yeah, for some reason I thought you could have more than one functional defined in the same way. Obviously I was confused. I think what's confused me was the fact they never used the word "defined as...", but rather it had to "satisfy $(\delta|\varphi) = \varphi(0).$"

Comment: @Hyperplane Just a question, what does it mean for it to be "non-regular" then? Why have all these requirements on test functions when we can define $(\delta|\varphi) := \varphi(0)$ for all functions $\varphi$ defined on $\mathbb R$?  I mean, my book seems to use Dirac delta integral as a purely notational thing...

Comment: @MarkusKlyver A distribution $\psi$ is regular if and only if there exists a function $f_\psi$ such that $(\psi\mid\varphi) = \int f_\psi \cdot \varphi dx$ for all test functions $\varphi$. And yes, for a non-regular distribution $\xi$, writing $\int \xi \cdot \varphi dx$ instead of $(\xi\mid\varphi)$ is, at the end of the day, a purely notational thing.

Comment: @Hyperplane Then why bother with all requirements for test functions, if ìt's a notational thing anyway?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver The requirements are there so to ensure convergence in the case of regular distributions. You define the space of test functions the way you do so that any locally integrable function gives rise to a distribution. (e.g. $x^k, e^x, |x|, \text{sign}(x),\ldots$ all define regular distributions).

By letting the test functions have compact support, you ensure that the integrals $\int f \varphi dx $ converge and by letting them be smooth, you ensure the existence of the distributional derivative $(f'\mid\varphi) = -(f\mid\varphi')$

Comment: @MarkusKlyver For example $\text{sign}(x)$ has a derivative as a distribution, ($2\delta(x)$), but not as a function.


As you noted, the dirac delta is a bit special because the expression $(\delta\mid\varphi)$ makes sense even if $\varphi$ is only continuous instead of smooth and with compact support.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a second remark about the existence of $\delta$ as a function since this seems to cause you trouble.

Consider a map $f:A\to B$. Then $f$ can be identified with the set $\{(a,f(a)) \mid a\in A\} \subseteq A\times B$.

Hence questioning the existence of $\delta:S\to\mathbb C, \varphi \to \varphi(0)$ is the same as questioning whether or not the set

$$\{(\varphi,\varphi(0))\mid\varphi\in S\} \subset S\times \mathbb C$$

exists.